# How to know what anchors to use on the ceiling?

Tags: ceiling-fan

I am a beginner DIY'er trying to install a ceiling fan. The instructions say to use the appropriate fixing for the type of ceiling you have. This is rather obvious but what isn't so obvious is what kind of ceiling I actually have and how to go about finding that out. So my question is: How do you know what material the ceiling is made out of so that you can choose the correct anchor?

Comment: What country are you located in? Different regions have different building practices and that might help to narrow down the possibilities. Also, how old is your house (or at least that portion of the house)?

Comment: What is not obvious to us is what kind of ceiling fan you have. In North America ceiling fans do not use anchors, they are attached to an electrical box in the ceiling and the box is attached to wooden structure inside the ceiling to insure that the heavy weight of the fan will not  cause it to fall, I.E. pull out the anchors. **Please give us much more and detailed information**.

Comment: You are thinking first you attach the fan to the ceiling, then as an afterthought you figure out how to hook up the wires.  Actually, it's the reverse.  The wiring method *provides for the fan mounting* because you use electrical junction boxes specifically made to support fans.

Comment: @Harper It may not be a ceiling fan like you or i know of. I have been in many countries where it is common to have an oscillating fan ( like a floor fan ) that is mounted to a wall or ceiling and the cord is run to an outlet. That is why i asked for more info.

Comment: @Dave I am located in Spain. The house was built after year 2000. I don't think things work the same here as they do in the US but I was hoping to get an idea about how you might go about figuring out what material is used.

Comment: @Alaska man: I know in North America it is different because the ceilings are usually different. The ceiling fan I have is this one http://www.leroymerlin.es/fp/81878656/ventilador-de-techo-con-luz-led-inspire-autan and according to the instructions it is fixed to the ceiling using anchors. It wasn't my intention to ask how to install the thing but rather a general question to try and figure out how know what a ceiling is made out of for this and future installations. Surely you need to know this before installing anything in the ceiling

Comment: @Harper All the rooms in my home have 3 electricity cables in the middle of the room coming out of the ceiling for lighting or ceiling fans. The cables seem to run through a layer of plaster. So at least as a starting point one could assume that there is a layer of plaster but since it is not hollow behind the plaster, could it be concrete? Brick? Wood? Does one just have to drill a hole and see?

Comment: You can't tell the difference between concrete, brick, and wood? Uh, that's not good...

Answer (score 1):

Common ways to find out how the ceiling is constructed include ...

- finding an existing opening, e.g. for a ceiling light, and having a good look in and poke around.
- asking a neighbour whose house was built by the same building company at the same time
- using a stud detector and wiring detector to see how uniform the ceiling is and location of any wires near the surface
- drilling a small hole and seeing what comes out.

I believe many 21st century European homes have concrete-slab ceilings rather than traditional wooden joists.

Comment: thanks, good reply! Do concrete slab ceilings have metal inside them? When I google the term: "concrete slab ceiling" I get all kinds of different results.

Comment: @armand: I don't know for certain but I would expect they must contain steel rod reinforcement. Concrete is strong in compression but weak in tension. The reinforcement helps resist tension. In concrete "beam and block" floors, the beams are pre-stressed by putting tension on embedded steel rods. The blocks are not prestressed so far as I know.

Comment: thanks again. Would a stud detector detect metal rods within concrete in the ceiling? Also can a stud detector detect electricity cables? thanks

Comment: Stud detector are for detecting studs in drywall. They are not for concrete. Concrete is dense enough that all of it is a "stud" according to the stud detector.  For concrete, you typically use concrete anchors and those are quite strong when installed correctly. Your goal is to avoid the reinforcement rods, but you typically can't find them until you drill into it, and if you happen to hit a rod, fill it and drill somewhere else.